# viewDidAppear is calling when self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) is called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

i have cab management application where a class called **corecontroller** is extended from **UIViewcontroller** to use all common functions . Here we are added notification observer and remover

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //registering gcm reciever
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(showReceivedGCMMessageCore(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: appDelegate.messageKey), object: nil)
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: appDelegate.messageKey), object: nil)
}
```

In **MyViewController**

```
class MyViewController: Corecontroller{
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  }
  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
 }
}
```

when FCM arrives it will exicute functions inside **corecontroller** , in that one of the functionality is to open a page say **AcceptReqeustViewcontroller** from my extended corecontroller , in this **AcceptReqeustViewcontroller** when user accept the request need to  dismiss back to a viewcontroller so i did

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let rootController   = kStoryBoard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:kViewControllers.mainPage) as! MainViewController

    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootController

    self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

initialized new viewcontroller as rootviewcontroller and dismissed but in this case in **MyViewController** `viewDidAppear()` function getting executed just want to know why this is happening?

Comment: Because it's legal in mvc

Comment: if you don't want this behaviour just set `modelPresentationStyle` to `currentContext` or `overCurrentContext`

Comment: @SPatel where i can change the `modelPresentationStyle` ?

Comment: On controller that you are going to present